# Does WKInterfaceController pop() deletes popped Controller?

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I've been trying to figure out why the first time I push to a WatchKit view it's didAppear() runs but the second time, after popping it, it finishes the push command then crashes right after without running didAppear().

I've been using:

```
WKExtension.shared().rootInterfaceController.pop()
```

to return to the previous view. Is this deleting the popped view? And if so is there a way to save the view so I can push it again? pop() does not return the view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are popping (removing from the navigation stack) the root interface controller instead of the current interface controller. You are basically trying to remove the interface controller from which all other controllers were pushed. Imagine if you were building a jenga tower and instead of removing a brick from the top, you removed the one on the bottom. Of course your tower would collapse.

Depending on what you actually want to achieve, you either need to call `self.pop()` or `self.popToRootController()` in your current interface controller. The former will just move back to the previous controller if you have more than two interface controller on the navigation stack, while the latter will always return to the root interface controller regardless of how many you have in the stack.

Comment: Finally got a chance to check this and after moving the pop command to the view's controller (self.pop() with the controller that needs to be popped) rather than running using the root interface controller and it's still crashing like it did before. According to the documentation pop() pops the current view (top of the navigation stack) not the view that calls it so it shouldn't matter whether I pop it with the root controller or the current controller.

Comment: Please include more code in your question to see what the exact issue might be then. Also, "it crashes" isn't specific enough, please include the exact error message you receive.

Comment: The problem isn't with the pop. I was certain it as that's where it keeps breaking but simply testing push, pop, push works fine so it's somewhere else. There's no error message but the break point's during a nopl execution which doesn't seem to make sense as, from my understanding, that's not actually doing anything. I'll start a new question if I figure out where it is and need more help since this question is wrong.